# What is special about a double-slash-star comment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, comments, syntax-highlighting

So I've come across some interesting JS comment syntax in the past (e.g. `/*!` for minifiers, `*` on new lines in block comments, encapsulated string literals, etc) but recently I've been seeing more of `//*` to start off comments.

After trying it out in my editor, I discovered many popular themes actually highlight these comments in special colors to stand out to the user. Naturally I use it to signal more important notes and method specifications, but I'm wondering what the actual usage of `//*` comments is. Does it actually signal anything to some software (like a minifier?) or is it safe to use as a stylistic choice?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
// normal comment
//* would be some accent color in many editors
```

[image: Double Slash Star Comment Accent Color]

FWIW this does not occur with slash-star (`/*`) block comments, but there is an accent color present on new lines within the block comment that begin with `*`, although this is more of a standard styling choice so I don't believe they are related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just to highlight an important note

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments